# How to handle Call during crash?

Tags: java, android, crash, telephonymanager

I'm working on a phone-conference app on Android 7. I found this problem.
When app crash I loose ongoing call control resulting in app closed and voice channel open.
Reopening app result in two ongoing calls.
There are ways to close the first voice call?

I try closing the call at app restart but obviously Android OS don't let me touch it.
the best (still not working) result I achieved is error class extension. that event is fired at crash start.

here is my class CrashKillCall that implements `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`

```
public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    //"the last song kill the audience" by Crash & the boys
    Log.e(TAG, "--------------------------------------");
    Log.e(TAG,t.getName());
    Log.e(TAG,e.getCause().getMessage());
    Log.e(TAG, "--------------------------------------");
    crashCall.disconnect();
    Log.e(TAG,"work?");
}
public static void setCall(Call call){
    crashCall=call;
}
```

the desired result is some way to, or to let system know that i want to, terminate the ongoing or all calls. 
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended out that i was pointing at wrong Call object. code work, you just need declare an istance of that class as default exception listener and register the right Call